# Meteor Routers Killing Helpers

Tags: node.js, meteor, router, iron-router

I've been messing around with this Basic Basic chat room while trying to learn Meteor.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/real-time-messaging-for-meteor-with-meteor-streams/
However, I wanted to create chat 'rooms' and discovered I needed to install Router, or Iron Router both after installing kill this basic chat room and I get the error...

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'helpers' of undefined

The chat works fine on the first go, but not after installing Router/Iron-Router and then it never works again, after uninstalling router/iron-router.

Please help :)

Comment: how did you uninstall it?

Comment: mrt remove router/iron-router

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but meteorite does not cleanly remove pacakges. You have to do a little manual work. See [this issue](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/163) for how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for that info, I'll remember that for the future. However, I do want router or Iron-router installed and helpers working. My end goal is to have a simple basic chatroom with 'rooms'. I assume, I need both router and helpers if I were to use that basic example?

Comment: have you narrowed down where the error is thrown? Can you paste that code? Did the error appear immediately after installing a router or only once you also changed the route to the page where you want to use the helper?

Comment: I've used the example code line by line. Anywhere it references helpers the code throws errors.  I shut down the server and added router by mrt add router and then started it by mrt run and after that the example chat was dead.  I didn't add any router code to my project I just have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

if mrt remove router/iron-router  doesnt solve your problem

1. check .meteor/packages file for iron-router or router packages. if exists
   remove them from this file.
2. check smart.json for iron-router or router packages. if exists
   remove them from this file.
3. delete the appropriate package directory from packages/iron-router or packages/router